# Any good use for nested function in C?

Tags: c, nested-function

I read somewhere that nested functions are permissible in C (at least the GNU compiler allows it).  Consider the following code:

```
/* nestedfunc.c */
#include <stdlib.h> /* for atoi(3) */
#include <stdio.h>

int F (int q)
{
  int G (int r)
  {
    return (q + r);
  }
  return (G (5));
}

int main (int argc, const char* argv[])
{
  int q = 0;
  if (argc > 1)
  {
    q = atoi (argv[1]);
  }

  printf ("%d\n", F (q));
  return 0;
}
```

Compiling and running:

```
gcc -o nestedfunc -O2 -s -Wall nestedfunc.c
me@mybox:~/college/c++/other stuff$ ./nestedfunc 8
13
me@mybox:~/college/c++/other stuff$
```

I've also read that some other programming languages support these.  My question is this:  What useful purpose does a nested function have?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's important to realize that these are not even remotely standard but a compiler-specific extension, so if you care at all about portability, you stay away from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nested functions provide [encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28computer_science%29#Encapsulation) through [lexical scope](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_%28programming%29#Lexical_scoping).

In your example, `G()` can only be called by `F()` and by other functions defined within `F()`.

Comment: Especially in C and other languages without namespaces (e.g. PHP until 5.x in theory, most PHP today in practice), it could be extremely useful to avoid namespace pollution.

Comment: @delnan: I fail to see how this is useful. C has `static` scope, and if that's not enough to avoid name clashes, you can simply prepend `your_favorite_uuid_your_main_function_name_` to the names of its helper functions.

Comment: @R.. `your_favorite_uuid_your_main_function_name_` is *the* killer reason for namespaces. Also, I said "namespace **pollution** " - you can avoid name clashes, but you're polluting the global namespace anyway unless you use `static` or nested functions to limit scope.

Comment: I'd be hesitant to call it *pollution* as long as the name chosen has no practical chance of clashing with a name chosen by another library or application. Sure it's ugly, but it doesn't break anything. And even with namespaces, you have to ensure that the names of namespaces don't clash.

Answer (score 3):

Nested functions can access the outer function's locals. Somewhat like closures, you can take a pointer to a nested function and pass this pointer to other functions, and the nested function will have access to the current invocation's locals (bad things happen if this invocation has already returned). Because the C runtime system is not designed for this, a function pointer is generally just a pointer to the first instruction of the function and pointers to nested functions can only be done by writing some code on the stack and passing a pointer to that. This is a bad idea from a security perspective.

If you want to use nested functions, use a language with a runtime system with proper support for them. To achieve a similar result in C, put "the outer function's locals" in a context structure and pass this along manually.

Comment: +1 for explaining the only real use for gcc nested functions.

Answer (score 1):

In general, a nested function is usually a helper function, which is only used inside one other function. It's sort of like a `static` function (with file scope) but even more localised (only function scope).

Nested functions are not standard C, so there's little reason to use them in that language.

Answer (score 0):

In other programming languages (like Python, Ruby for example) functions are first class objects. You have [closures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29) which are powerful abstraction concept. In python you can do this:

```
def curry(func):
    from inspect import getfullargspec
    args = getfullargspec(func)
    num_args = len(args[0])

    def new_func(list_args, *args):
        l = len(list_args) + len(args)
        nl = list_args + list(args)
        if l > num_args:
             raise TypeError("Too many arguments to function")
        elif l == num_args:
             return func(*nl)
        else:
             return lambda *new_args: new_func(nl, *new_args)

    return lambda *args: new_func([], *args)
```

That is curry decorator which takes a function and makes it curried.

Comment: Note the "in C" in the title. Higher-order functions in C... my eyes bleed when I think about how that would look like :(

Comment: "I've also read that some other programming languages support these. My question is this: What useful purpose does a nested function have? Thanks in advance." I answered this. :)

Comment: Yes. I was simply love making snarky remarks about C :) (Unrelated: I wonder whether OP will acknowledge this as useful. In my experience, many don't consider all this fancy FP stuff useful until they actually use it)